# Laravel - Inserting into database, optional field chaining

Tags: php, laravel, chaining

Every user in my app can add an appointment. An appointment must contain a `label` and a `status`. There are a few relations set up between them all, as seen below. Every user can add their own `labels` and `statuses`, as well as `appointments`.

In my appointment create form, I will display a dropdown of the users' labels and statuses. But, also an empty field below those dropdowns, so the user can decide to create a new label or status on the fly.

My question is, is it possible to save the appointment in the database in one go (chaining), so that the new label and/or status will be saved (if either one is submitted)? My current saving method is like so:

```
Auth::user()->appointments()->create($request->all());
```

But this is without including any new labels or statuses that the user submits. Is it possible what I want, or should I be doing it like this instead?

```
    if($request->label_name)
    {
        Auth::user()->labels()->create($request->label_name);
    }
```

First create a new label, if submitted. And then something like:

```
    Auth::user()->appointments()->create([
        $request->appointment->name,
        $request->label_id // Figure out a way to get the last inserted label_id
    ]);
```

The reason I am asking this is, because I want to keep it simple, and if there is an easy way of accomplishing this, that would be great. This is all for learning purposes btw, so any answer is a good answer.

Appointment Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function label()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Label::class);
}

public function status()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Status::class);
}
```

User Model:

```
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Appointment::class);
}

public function labels()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Label::class);
}

public function statuses()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Status::class);
}
```

Label & Status Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function appointments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Appointment::class);
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong with creating a label first then using its id when creating appointments?

Comment: Nothing wrong with it, was just wondering if I could chain it somehow, just want to learn different approaches :)

Comment: Nah you can't really "chain" this as there is dependancy of appointments on labels, so label must exist first. Unless you make that optional ;)

Comment: Yeah true :) Thanks for the comments